# Should quoted clause be capitalized

Tags: capitalization, quotations, quotation-marks

I wonder if a quoted clause should be capitalized or not. For example, which of the following sentences is correct:

1. For instance, "he is less than 20 years old" contains a subject and
   a subject complement.
2. For instance, "He is less than 20 years old"
   contains a subject and a subject complement.

Comment: If it were a sentence it would have a period at the end.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you mean there should be a period, or that the word "sentence" is technically not correct, and the OP should have said, "clause" instead? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different schools of thought on this. On the one hand, it constitutes a complete sentence on its own, so upper case could be justified. On the other hand, it functions as an integral sentence constituent (a subject), so lower case could be justified.[1] Whichever you pick, be sure to be consistent throughout the text.

[1] The Chicago Manual of Style (I'm using the 14th ed.) says: "A quotation used as an essential syntactic part of a sentence . . . may begin with a lowercase letter even though the original is a complete sentence beginning with a capital."